# Lebesgue Integral defined on infinite measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Royden's Real Analysis Question: Let {$a_n$} be a sequence of nonnegative real numbers. Define the function $f$ on $E=[1,\infty)$ by setting $f(x)=a_n$ if $n\leq x< n+1$. I want to show that $\int_Ef=\sum{a_n}$. The summation is infinite.

I don't even know how to approach this problem. It's just so confusing. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int _E f=\int_{\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty[n,n+1)}f=\int_Ef\cdot\chi_{\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty[n,n+1)}=$$
$$\int_Ef\cdot \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\chi_{[n,n+1)}=\int_E\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f\cdot\chi_{[n,n+1)}\overset{\mbox{Levi}}{=}$$
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\int_Ef\cdot\chi_{[n,n+1)}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \int_{[n,n+1)}f=$$
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \int_{[n,n+1)}a_n=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n\cdot\mu ([n.n+1))=$$
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$

**Beppo Levi's theorem** is an application of Monotone Convergence theorem which allows the switch between integral and infinite sums of non-negative terms.

Comment: Ahhh why cant my brains work with this finesse!! thanks a ton..just one issue; what do you mean by levi above the equal sign?

Comment: I apply Levi's theorem. See the note at the bottom I added

Comment: ohh yes this was in the notes but the professor didn't go through it so I forgot to check it. but thanks for mentioning it as well!